# Is it okay to query a GitHub resource from multiple IPs without using GitHub API?

Tags: github, curl, github-pages, github-api

I'm developing an app that would download codes from GitHub once in a while. The queries (per IP) will stay waaay under the limits listed on the GH documentation (QPM && QPH). The queries are simple cUrls to HTTP GitHub code pages (raw) without passing through the API.

Let's suppose 50k users will query a GH resource on the same day: are the queriers risking some kind of ban?

[Limits 1](https://docs.github.com/en/rest/overview/resources-in-the-rest-api#rate-limiting)

[Limits 2](https://docs.github.com/en/rest/reference/search#rate-limit)

Answer (score 0):

The rate limits for the raw and archive endpoints (which are the same service) are currently the same as for authenticated API endpoints: 5000 per hour.  It does sometimes happen that, due to the way the rate-limiting works, the actual number of requests you can make is higher, but you should not rely on that.

In general, those endpoints are not designed to be a CDN or code distribution network for your app.  They're designed instead to provide easy access for individual users to the raw contents of a few files instead of having to clone the entire repository.  If you do this anyway and end up using excessive resources for your repository, GitHub Support will reach out to you and ask you to stop, and your repository may be suspended if you don't cause the excessive resource use to be stopped promptly.

If you are going to make *any* sort of automated requests to those endpoints, it's strongly recommended that you use a unique `User-Agent` header in your library so they can be effectively identified, and preferably that that header contain some sort of identifying information (a URL or email address related to the project) so that you can be contacted about problems.

Your app should also gracefully handle errors like 403 and 429 and back off or stop trying to connect.  This is true of every HTTP client.

If you want to distribute code or assets for your app, you should do so using a CDN backed by a server you control rather than the GitHub raw endpoints.  You should be sure to serve this data over HTTPS and implement a secure digital signature mechanism to prevent malicious code or assets from being distributed.